# Multiple Polynomial Regression / Dictionary Learning with unknown Vandermonde dictionary

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus, regression, matrix-decomposition, interpolation

The question is not technical, but more to receive possible suggestions of applicability and applications of a particular mathematical model.

Consider the observation model $y_i= w_0 + w_1 x_i + \ldots + w_L x_i^K$, where $y_i$ is a scalar value expressed as a polynomial regression of a quantity $x_i$. Collecting $N$ observations $y_i$ and stacking them in a vector $y \in \mathbb{R}^N$, the overall model can be expressed in matrix vector form as

$$y= V(x)w$$

where $V(x)$ is the Vandermonde matrix
$$V(x)= [1 \; x \; x^2 \cdots x^{K-1}]$$

where the power of each vector is to be considered element-wise. In this case $w \in \mathbb{R}^K$ , while $x \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Each row of this system expresses the observation model introduced at the beginning.

Assume that I also collect $L$ measurement vectors such as $y$ and I stack them in the matrix $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times L}$. I can express the model as

$$Y= V(x)W$$
with $W \in \mathbb{R}^{K \times L} $ collecting the parameters of the model.

My question is: which examples of systems do follow such polynomial relationship? More importantly, in which contexts might it be of interest to learn not only the regression parameters $W$, but also the Vandermonde dictionary $V(x)$ itself? Clearly a straightforward algorithm would learn $V(x)$ and $W$ with some ambiguity. Are there applications in which we might be satisfied also with such ambiguities?

Similar problems are found in neural networks, where oftentimes a local minimum is satisfactory, especially when the learned parameters need not be interpretable.

Comment: Polynomials can be used to approximate any smooth enough curve with regression although we may be wise to apply some regularization. If you also allow complex x you can also get any discretized trigonometric polynomial. I think this may be considered way too broad a question for this site. You can basically do anything with it.

Comment: Yes, it is a broad question and the answer can be broad as well. I would like to understand if there are some scenarios in which you can 1) measure the output of a system, 2) assume that unknown input and output have a polynomial relationship 3) learn the coefficients of the polynomials and the input generating the output. Perhaps you want to compress data in the dictionary and you do not care about the identifiability of the true input.. I am just throwing some ideas